# Merging elements of two different arrays to third array

Tags: php, arrays

I wish you could help me ...
I have 2 arrays, which I would like to insert into a 1array, by `new_date` to which if there is no `data` is `data` = '0', if there is no `data1` is `data1` = '0'.

Sorry if I do not know how to explain it well, I gave a small example. I have already tried array_merge (but everything is separate) and array_combine (it gives an error of Both parameters should have an equal number of elements).
**Thank you** in advance for all the help you can give ...

```html
array1 = array:5 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 118
        "new_date" => "06-2017"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 263
        "new_date" => "07-2017"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 264
        "new_date" => "08-2017"
      ]
      3 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 266
        "new_date" => "09-2017"
      ]
      4 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 306
        "new_date" => "10-2017"
      ]
      5 => array:2 [▼
        "data" => 100
        "new_date" => "11-2017"
      ]
```

```html
array2 = array:6 [▼
      0 => array:2 [▼
        "data1" => 100
        "new_date" => "02-2016"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [▼
        "data1" => 170
        "new_date" => "06-2017"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [▼
        "data1" => 354
        "new_date" => "07-2017"
      ]
      3 => array:2 [▼
        "data1" => 397
        "new_date" => "08-2017"
      ]
      4 => array:2 [▼
        "data1" => 421
        "new_date" => "09-2017"
      ]
      5 => array:2 [▼
        "data1" => 531
        "new_date" => "10-2017"
      ]
```

**Exemple:**

```html
array3 = array:7 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "data1" => 111
        "data" => 0
        "new_date" => "02-2016"
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "data1" => 170
        "data" => 118
        "new_date" => "06-2017"
      ]
      2 => array:3 [▼
        "data1" => 354
        "data" => 263
        "new_date" => "07-2017"
      ]
      3 => array:3 [▼
        "data1" => 397
        "data" => 264
        "new_date" => "08-2017"
      ]
      4 => array:3 [▼
        "data1" => 421
        "data" => 266
        "new_date" => "09-2017"
      ]
      5 => array:3 [▼
        "data1" => 531
        "data" => 306
        "new_date" => "10-2017"
      ]
      6 => array:3 [▼
        "data1" => 0
        "data" => 100
        "new_date" => "11-2017"
      ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to set the `new_date` as keys. Then add the first array element the `d1` (as "data1" in your example) with `array_map`. Finely, loop on second array and add `d1` is exist and all the rest with `d` ("data" in your example) as 0 if not.

You can do it like this:

```
$a1 = array(["d"=>1, "new_date"=> "06-2017"],["d"=>2, "new_date"=> "02-2016"]);
$a2 = array(["d1"=>3, "new_date"=> "06-2017"],["d1"=>4, "new_date"=> "07-2017"]);

$a1 = array_combine(array_column($a1, "new_date"), $a1);
$a2 = array_combine(array_column($a2, "new_date"), $a2);

// adding default d1 as 0
$a1 = array_map(function ($e) {return array_merge($e, ["d1" => 0]);},$a1);

foreach($a2 as $k => $v) {
    if (isset($a1[$k]))
        $a1[$k]["d1"] = $v["d1"]; // if new_data exist set only d1
    else
        $a1[$k] = array_merge($v, ["d" => 0]); //add with d as 0
}
```

Your result will be in `$a1`